# HttpClient logging sensitive data

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, dotnet-httpclient

Is it possible to disable logging headers of requests/responses performed using `HttpClient` at every log level?

Registering custom HttpClient into DI like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient<CustomHttpClient>(config =>
{
    config.BaseAddress = new Uri(CustomBaseAddress);
    config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new(AuthorizationKey, AuthorizationValue);
});
```

After request is performed logs are looking like this:

```
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CustomHttpClient.LogicalHandler
      Start processing HTTP request GET {CustomBaseAddress}
trce: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CustomHttpClient.LogicalHandler
      Request Headers:
      Authorization: {AuthorizationKey} {AuthorizationValue}
```

I know I can set min log level in app configuration for `System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CustomHttpClient` to `none` (or something higher that trace). But I want to avoid doing that.

So is there a way how to configure HttpClient to not logging headers?

Comment: What version of asp.net core are you using? If 6, you might enable the new httplogging middleware. If earlier, you might need to implement an http logging middleware yourself. Please check https://josef.codes/asp-net-core-6-http-logging-log-requests-responses/

Comment: @ruzgarustu The http-logging middleware is for the opposite scenario: logging incoming requests (and outgoing responses) on the server-side. HttpClient logging is, like the name implies, for logging outgoing requests and incoming respones (so "client-side").

Comment: @Christian.K Yes, in this case I'm using HttpClient for sending request to a server.

Comment: Configure logging to not log source `"System.Net.Http.HttpClient!"` (or maybe only warnings and up).

Comment: @Richard As I mentioned in this Question I want to disable logging headers on every log level.

Comment: @PetrNečas I'm pretty sure such control does not exist. To be sure you would need to check the source code of the helpers you're using (`HttpClient` itself does not reference `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`): perhaps using `HttpClient` more directly, and using your own wrapper in DI?

Comment: I think the whole approach is based on creating a custom message handler for an `HttpClient`  instance, and it is the handler that does the logging. Replacing the applicable factory in DI might be a route to customisation. But to be honest, your use case may just be better handled with something completely custom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally ended up with pretty easy solution. And its by using extension method [HttpClientBuilderExtensions.RedactLoggedHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.redactloggedheaders?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Example:

```
services.AddHttpClient<CustomHttpClient>(config =>
{
    config.BaseAddress = new Uri(CustomBaseAddress);
    config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new(AuthorizationKey, AuthorizationValue);
})
.RedactLoggedHeaders(new string[] { "Authorization" });
```

This method hides headers values before logging.

from this:

```
trce: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CustomHttpClient.LogicalHandler
      Request Headers:
      Authorization: {AuthorizationKey} {AuthorizationValue}
```

to this:

```
trce: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CustomHttpClient.LogicalHandler
      Request Headers:
      Authorization: *
```